# What's the difference between (re)invoking a coroutine and awaiting it?

Tags: coroutine, c++20, c++-coroutine

I have been late on getting into co-routines; but now that C++20 has them, I'm dipping my toes, so to speak. Specifically, I watched a segment on coroutines in [this CppCon20 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImLFlLjSveM) by Timur Doumler.

Timur first explains the use of co-routines with a function and a coroutine (or rather, coroutine and associated generator):

```
my_generator<int> f() {
 int i = 0;
 while (true)
   co_yield i++;
}

void foo() {
  auto g = f();
  std::cout << g() << '\n';
  std::cout << g() << '\n';
  std::cout << g() << '\n';
}
```

Later in the segment, he introduces `co_await`, with this example:

```
async_generator<T> f1() { 
  // code
  auto u = co_await f2();
  // more code
  co_return u;
}

async_generator<U> f2() {
  // code
  co_yield u;
}
```

Now, what I don't understand is how this second example differs from just invoking the coroutine like in the first example, e.g.:

```
async_generator<T> f1() {
  auto g2 = f2();
  // code
  auto u = g2();
  // more code
  co_return u;
}

async_generator<U> f2() {
  // code
  co_yield u;
}
```

I tried looking for [`co_await` on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/co_await), and that exists, but - it links to the general [coroutines page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) - and to be honest, I can't see the forest from the trees. I would rather not know about all the details - for now. I just want to understand the high-level conceptual difference.

Comment: There is no reinvocation of `f`; calling the generator it returns corresponds to performing a `co_await`, although obviously it differs not only in that it happens multiple times per coroutine execution but also in that it cannot suspend the caller.

Comment: @DavisHerring: "reinvocation" is just a figure of speech. Regardless - calling a function; co_awaiting a coroutine; calling a generator - all of these suspend the caller until something is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The `co_yield` statement makes sense only in the presence of a *suspension context*. An example of a suspension context for a generator is the usage of co_yield inside a loop (yielding a value for some condition).

In this example:

```
async_generator<T> f1() { 
  // code
  auto u = co_await f2();
  // more code
  co_return u;
}

async_generator<U> f2() {
  // code
  co_yield u;
}
```

the co_yeild is not associated with any suspension context, therefore it would work as a typical function (ie., co_yield being interpreted as a normal return statement). `auto u` would wait until `f2` reaches the end of the function thereby making the execution work as a typical *function call* semantic.

In this example:

```
async_generator<T> f1() {
  auto g2 = f2();
  // code
  auto u = g2();
  // more code
  co_return u;
}

async_generator<U> f2() {
  // code
  co_yield u;
}
```

Again, the suspension context is missing due to a lack of creation and manipulation of a *promise object*. Therefore, the code would work exactly the same as the previous example.

If, however, the examples differed by the suspension context, then co_yield might have worked differently.

Authoritative explanations of the interactions between co-routines and promise-objects (using co_await, and co_yield) is found [here](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#def:promise_object) .

Comment: 1. I don't think this actually answers my question. 2. They're not my examples. 3. I would hope for an explanation which doesn't require me knowing about the promise objects (unless you tell me it's imperative to understand them).

Comment: I changed the wording a little bit to reflect point 2. Afaik, I honestly believe promise objects are associated with asynchronous programming in all modern languages such as python, c#, and in c++. Some micro-processor programming in C can let go of the promise-object abstraction by leveraging the inherent hardware layout. However, afaik, a high-level programming language model uses promise-objects.